# How to deserialize xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am load xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderHeadUpload xmlns="http://www.sample-package.org" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Number>Z-00006453580748</Number>
    <Number_confirm>000033477</Number_confirm>
    <Positions>
        <id>168816</Product_id>
        <Tare_id>2442</Tare_id>
    </Positions>
</OrderHeadUpload>
```

Make 2 class

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Head", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
    public class OrderHeadUpload
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number_confirm", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
        public string Client_id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
        public string Barcode_id { get; set; }
    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Positions", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
    public class Positions
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tare_id", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
        public string  Tare_id {get; set;}
    }
```

i am load xml file (temp.xml) then serializer on classes 2 Position and Head
then StringReader, which reads strings from a file
and then `var position = (Positions) serializer.Deserialize (reader);` class serialized become deserialized

```
    doc.Load(temp);

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Positions));
    XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Head));

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(temp);

    var position = (Positions)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    var Head = (OrderHeadUpload)serializer2.Deserialize(reader);
```

but i see error 
Error msg There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
Where?:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at .cs:line 64 (var position = (Positions)serializer.Deserialize(reader);)

How to correctly deserialize this xml?

Comment: Your code snippets don't add up. What you posted would not compile. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Positions", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
public class Positions
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tare_id", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
    public string Tare_id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Head", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
public class OrderHeadUpload
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number_confirm", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
    public string Client_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number", Namespace = "http://www.sample-package.org")]
    public string Barcode_id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Positions")]
    public Positions positions;
}
```

Use:

```
var order = (OrderHeadUpload)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

And you need to deserialize just onetime with `OrderHeadUpload`. If you have more than one Positions, you can declare like a `List<T>`